# Filtering on pointcloud using cloudcompare

Tags: filtering, point-cloud-library

I want to perform a few filtering techniques on pointcloud data (given '.ply' file).
I wondered if it is possible to perform the filtering techniques such as
`omnivariance`, `anisotropic` using [cloudcompare](https://www.danielgm.net/cc/)? There are hardly any tutorials available on the internet! I would appreciate your time. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, sharing it because this may help others.
Tools>other>Compute geometric features.